# Why is : $ \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) / J \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) \cong \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) / J' \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $ V $ be a non empty variety in $ \mathbb{A}^n $. Let $ P \in V $.

We define $ \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $ to be the set of rational functions on $ V $ that are defined at $ P $.

$ \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $ is called the local ring of $ V $ at $ P $.

Let $ I = I(V) \subset k[X_1 , \dots , X_n ] $ and let $ J $ be an ideal of $ k[X_1 , \dots , X_n ] $ that contain $ I $.

Let $ J' $ be the image of $ J $ in the coordinate ring $ \Gamma (V) $.

- How to show that there is a natural homomorphism $ \varphi \ : \ \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) / J \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) \to \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) / J' \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $, and that $ \varphi $ is an isomorphism.
  In particular,  $ \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) / J \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) $ is isomorphic to $ \mathcal{O}_P (V) $.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about it in terms of quotients (of quotients) and localizations, and how they all commute (according to natural isomorphisms).

Comment: I don't really understand. In my opinion, we need to construct a homomorphism : $ \varphi \ : \ \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) \to \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $ such that $ \varphi ( J \mathcal{O}_P ( \mathbb{A}^n ) ) \subset J' \mathcal{O}_P ( V ) $, right ? How ?